# LensProp Type Definition of Ramda

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, ramda.js

When using Ramda's `lensProp` like:

```
R.lensProp('x')
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks you need to pass in the type that you expect the `lensProp` to operate on, so that it knows what type to return when used. You can do that by passing in the generic parameter.

Here's the modified [example from the docs](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensProp) that plays nice with typescript:

```
import R from 'ramda'

interface Point {
    x: number
    y: number
}

const xLens = R.lensProp<Point>('x');

R.view(xLens, {x: 1, y: 2});            //=> 1
R.set(xLens, 4, {x: 1, y: 2});          //=> {x: 4, y: 2}
R.over(xLens, R.negate, {x: 1, y: 2});  //=> {x: -1, y: 2}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&strict=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJTgMyhEcDkUCGIAmOmAsAFBnAB2MAplMjgMY1wAKEV8A3mXH3AA8AXHEoBXEACM6vfgE8R4qTNIBfMmUYRKAZ3gCAMjV1wAvIgB0AG2M7WaMAB52nAHwAKTAMwBKANwapAgWAG7ANADu7oa2ADRwXMJwAIzxCnAATKr+-Ll5APT5pq4pZME6NDDRRrrxACzxiSKpcOlZOXm5hcUJSQ2tIlllFhAhdNVxlpQ0AOY4tI1JLW3ZfnzdJU1wALTLg6pAA)